# Can I prevent a user from submitting malicious XSL code to hack the server?

Tags: php, xslt, xhtml, htmlpurifier

In my webpage, I am going allow clients (X)HTML. To avoid XSS, I will use [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), and disable the `<script>` tag (and some other dangerous tags).

Yet I would like to enable designers of those (X)HTML to use certain programming-like features, for example displaying a list of items, which would need a for-loop.

Then I came up with the idea that : **users submit the XSL code, I provide the XML with the data required by the users.**

As HTML Purifier cannot sanitise XSL code (can it?), my proposed flow would be:

1. User submits a piece of XSL code.
2. In the server, there are some sample data (sample XMLs). PHP is used to do the XSL transform with those sample XML data.
3. Pass the output XHTML to HTML Purifier. If HTML Purifier detects any prohibited elements in the code, stop process and show the errors to user.
4. If it passes HTML Purifier, check it against the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/). (This is just a double check. Outputs from HTML Purifier should be valid.)
5. Save the piece of XSL code into database. Use (include) it whenever needed.

Do you think the flow above can assure the final XSL code saved into the database is clean (given that HTML Purifier is perfect)?

Another concern is that, (this is the main question here), is it safe to accept arbitrary XSL codes, and perform XSL transform by PHP in the server? Could there be any security holes that some XSS, injection, etc being included in the XSL codes, such that being harmful to the server or the PHP programs?

Finally, if there are any other ideas/design to achieve this, any solutions are welcomed!

Comment: @Mathias, Thanks for proofread. Please solve this question together :D

Comment: If you expect others to help you, at least accept the answers they have given so far.

Comment: What are the answers you mean?

Comment: You have asked many other questions so far and seldom accepted an answer - even if users have taken the time to formulate good and comprehensive answers.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Thanks for spotting. Let me review that question as soon as possible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43584/discussion-between-mathias-muller-and-midnite)

Comment: Sorry i am currently away from work (and any PC). Should you have any solutions, please contribute in the answers, which can benefit others as well. Thanks!

Comment: @UmNyobe, nice edit of title. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely not. XSL is Turing Complete and user-submitted XSL scripts can, at the very least, use up all your CPU, and at the very worst, run code on your server.

And even if the XSL is valid, there is absolutely no indication that a run on a single test input does not mean that the XSL cannot produce XSS output on specially crafted input.

Comment: WOW Thanks so so so much for spotting that **XSLT is a Turing-complete language** which can do anything that harm the server! For your second point, i guess it wont be a serious issue, as the XML is ensured to be clean. Test run of XSL transform will not only run against a single XML, but different ones, like "empty case" and "special cases". If outputs of all cases passed HTML Purifier, i assume the actual transformed XHTML will be clean. If my idea wasnt feasible, do you have any suggestions? If there arent any better solutions, this would definitely be the best answer.

Comment: do you think allowing only certain sub-set of XSLT functions could fix the problem while provide the features? For example, only allow `<xsl:for-each>`, `<xsl:if>`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to consider when allowing users to submit their own XSLT is that XSLT files are XML files themselves and could be open to things like [Billion Laughs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion_laughs) (XML bomb) attacks.

Comment: +1 Thanks for spotting this. There are really a lot of security concerns about this ....